# Deleting emails via POP3/IMAP in Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, imap, pop3

My question here is how exactly do I go about deleting emails by id in gmail utilizing POP3 or IMAP without utilizing Netcmdlets or another external dependency. If it helps, I have some C# code which does a variety of mailbox functions, but I have no idea how to translate it into Powershell because I have never worked with C# before.
https://github.com/andyedinborough/aenetmail/blob/master/Pop3Client.cs

Comment: Why do you need to translate it to PowerShell? Why not just compile it and use it as is?

Comment: How are you getting the id if you are not already connecting to the mailbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a full port to PowerShell, but you should be able to use the `Add-Type` cmdlet to add the C# source code, and call the methods within PowerShell.

Copy the source code into a `$Source` variable.

Add the referenced assemblies to an `$Assemblies` variable

Use `Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp -ReferencedAssemblies $Assemblies`

Execute the methods with `[AE.Net.Mail.Pop3Client]::MethodName()`

Here's a good reading about using C# code in PowerShell on [Technet](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2010/05/07/using-csharp-c-code-in-powershell-scripts/)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. I'm going to see if I can get it up and running.